# How to attach the build file in jenkins post build email?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am new to jenkins. I wish to know as to how to attach the build file generated , into the email sent as the post build action?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), which let you customize the email and attach the build file.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying.
What is the plugin name ? I cant find editable email notification plugin?
edit: Sorry I missed the link :) Thanks

Comment: if it is what you wanted, please mark the answer as correct and upvote the answer.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to attach the build file. It is an android (*.apk) file present inside a "bin" directory of the root folder. Can you help me there too?

Comment: you should be able to just add the path in the attachment inputfield, just make sure you are relative from the project directory.

Comment: you are wrong here the the file path is not relative to a project folder but to the workspace folder of jenkins.

Comment: yap. this is what i meant.

Comment: do we need to configure smtp or Jenkins's plugin will manage it ?

Comment: I am getting No emails were triggered.