# Sending email in Jenkins with body from content in file

Tags: jenkins

Ive downloaded plugin for jenkings to sending emails.
What I have is 2 files:

```
ReleaseNotes.txt
config.properties
```

The first one contains release notes in plain text, the second one contains the same release notes as properties file.
I can send them as attachment via this plug in, but I wish to add the content as mail content.

**Option 1: Somehow add content of ReleaseNotes.txt to my mail**

**Option 2: Set new environmental variable from config.properties and add them to mail.**

Esther one of the options will satisfy me, can you please help me with one of them? In your answer **please not just send me link to plugin** but actually help me and explain how to achieve it. I saw some plugins but I struggled using them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to attach the build file in jenkins post build email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717015/how-to-attach-the-build-file-in-jenkins-post-build-email)

Comment: Please read carefully my question again. I know how to attach file, what I wish is to send the content of file in mail body

Comment: Sorry, you weren't clear about the "mail body" requirements... please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494833/get-text-from-file-and-display-in-jenkins-email-content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to combine [Environment Script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin) plugin with [Email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) plugin to achieve the desired functionality.

Check the generate environment variable from script option in the build environment section.

Then create the script to read the file content, like this:

```
echo RELEASE_NOTES=$(cat ReleaseNotes.txt)
```

In the extended email notification configurations section, fill the default content field with your recently created variable `$RELEASE_NOTES`

Answer (score 30):

With the Email Extension Plugin v2.61 you can just do

```
<pre>
${FILE, path="file_name.txt"}
</pre>
```

in the Default Content session and keep the format

Comment: Is there any way to read and display excel content? If i replace path with excel path, it's printing random test `PK ,µÌP
_rels/.rels¬’ÁJ1 
†ï‚ïPrßéì
"²u/"ìMd}€ØffÊL›ÒF ßÞâE]w@Ác’æû?H·»9Lê…rñ 
¬›  EËÎÇÞÀãánuªF‡ G2  v7çgÛšPêN |*ªBb10ˆ¤k¬‹ (i8Q¬“Žs@©eîuB;bOzÓ¶—:eÀ1Uí��¼wkPÌ=‰�yÒ¯œÇ'æ±©à:xKô›Xî:oé–ís (Ò�^€^²Ù|Ú8¶÷™ë.¦ôß:4
`

Comment: Excel content is binary.  You can't add that in the body of an email.  Maybe you'd want to look into how to attach the file to the email or maybe parse the file and render something that could display as text/html int the body of the email.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Pipeline you can simply use the following script:

`emailext (to: 'email@email.com', replyTo: 'email@email.com', subject: "Email Report", body: readFile("target/site/serenity/index.html"), mimeType: 'text/html');`

In my case i was using serenity for reporting