# Jenkins: how to set body content from a variable

Tags: string, variables, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a scripted pipeline. In one of my steps I want to send different mails based on test results. Here is how I do it now:

```
if (buildResult == 'SUCESSS' 
    def email_body="TEST_SUCESS.template"
else
    def email_body="TEST_FAILURES.template"

    emailext(
            subject:  "Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}] finished",
            body: "${SCRIPT,template=$email_body}", // LINE A
            recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']],
            to: 'XXXX',
            from: 'YYYY',
            replyTo: 'ZZZZ',
            mimeType: 'text/html',
)
```

I can't have Jenkins expand the value of the variable *email_body*.  I've tried various approaches in the line A:

1. "${SCRIPT,template=$email_body}"
2. "${SCRIPT,template=${email_body}}"
3. '''${SCRIPT,template=$email_body}'''
4. '''${SCRIPT,template=${email_body}}'''

None of them works. All I get in the email is either:

> Groovy Template file [$email_body] was not found in $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates.

or

> ${SCRIPT,template=$email_body}.

What is the correct way of setting email content if the email content is stored in a variable?

Comment: Maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039633/sending-email-in-jenkins-with-body-from-content-in-file

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx, I can't see how it helps me. I don't want to see the variable in a bash script, but in a groovy pipeline.

Comment: ${SCRIPT,template=${email_body}}''' is searching for a template file in $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates. So, this is not the body. Read about  [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)

Comment: @JoaoVitorino, I have read about it. I placed a template in the $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates directory and I can use it if I don't use the email_body variable. The following works well for me: body: '''${SCRIPT,template="PM_TEST_FAILURES.template"}'''. However, I want to be able to dynamically set the body (the template) of my email based on test results.

Comment: I think that would be better put this logic on template. Pass to template the status of the build and in the template set the body as you like. [Email template example](https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/3604514/jenkins-matrix-email-html.template?version=1&modificationDate=1332562186000&api=v2)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this example:

```
String subject = "${env.JOB_NAME} was " + currentBuild.result.toString();
String email_body="TEST_" + currentBuild.result.toString() + ".template"
String body = "SCRIPT,template=" + email_body;
String to="some_mail@mail.com" 
String reply="ZZZ"
emailext(subject: subject, body: body, to: to, replyTo: reply);
```