# Jenkins reading a file from the build directory

Tags: email, jenkins

I am sending a post-build email out in Jenkins but instead of using the default email response I want to read the content in from a file that is stored in the job directory.

I've following the instructions here

[Sending email in Jenkins with body from content in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039633/sending-email-in-jenkins-with-body-from-content-in-file)

but, and this is a total noob question, what should the path to the file be?

My job path is (Mac laptop)

~/.jenkins/jobs/Github Test/files/email_text.txt

In the `Build Environment` section I selected `Generate environment variables from script` and added this line:

```
echo EMAIL_CONTENT=$(cat /files/email_text.txt)
```

and then in the `Post-build Actions` I selected `Editable Email Notification` and added `$EMAIL_CONTENT` for `Default Content`.

But the generated email came with no content. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file path must be relative to the workspace, you might want to try with `$(cat files/email_text.txt)` or `$(cat ./files/email_text.txt)`.

Answer (score 0):

I almost sure that is:

```sh
FILE_PATH="$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/$JOB_NAME/your-file.txt"
```

Comment: Also `$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/$JOB_NAME` can be substituted with `$WORKSPACE`.